# Cannot access ASP.NET Core application hosted in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, server, windows-services

I'm trying to create a ASP.NET core app which is hosted in a Windows Service, following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

The only difference I made is that I used [Network Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/networkservice-account) account, and made Kestrel listen to port 10090, instead of the default 5000.

After publish the binaries to the server(Windows Server 2012 R2), everything works fine via local access(on the server using http://localhost:10090/), but the web cannot be accessed on other PCs. Showing

```
This site can’t be reached
server-1 took too long to respond.
```

This server also has some IIS hosted web application and they are working fine.

Does anybody knows the missing points I made? Thanks!

Comment: Did you open a port in the firewall configuration on the hosting machine?

Comment: @CoolBots Yes, I added both inbound rules and outbound rules, but it still does not work.

Comment: why did you need outbound rules?

Comment: @CoolBots You're right, an outbound rule is not necessary. But the web still cannot be accessed :(

Comment: Although it should not be necessary, but have you tried restarting the hosting machine after the firewall rule was added?

Comment: @CoolBots I'm using a Windows Server 2012 as the host server, from my understanding, the rule should work without a restart, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

With help from my colleague I found that it is a programming issue.

When creating the `IWebHostBuilder` in Program.cs, I wrongly set the option of Kestrel (copy and paste from [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#kestrel-options)):

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 10090);
```

While one of the correct option is `IPAddress.Any`.